# Type mismatch error compiling vintage F77 code

Tags: input, fortran

I want to compile a computational code named [MOLSCAT](https://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/molscat/pub/v14.f) which uses a NAMELIST data as an input file like [Test](https://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/molscat/pub/test8.input). According to the main code, the compiler reads the input in channel 5. I put the input file in the main code folder and compiled the main code in Linux version of Simply Fortran. But with or without the input file, it gives the output

```
==============================================================
Generating Makefile... Okay
==============================================================
Compiling /home/farhad/Downloads/v14.f
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -   
  /home/farhad/Downloads/v14.f:2381:17:

   1    PARITY(IEXCH+JLEV(2*NLEV+I)+JTOT+JZCSFL*JLEV(IOFF+I)).LE.0.D0)
             1
   Error: 'mask' argument of 'parity' intrinsic at (1) must be LOGICAL
- - - - -  - - - -- - - - - -- - - - -- - - - - -- - --  -- - - -- - -
/home/farhad/Downloads/v14.f:10720:39:

 4000 CALL CPL24(N,MXLAM,LAM,NLEV,JLEV,JLEV,J,MVALUE,VL,PRINT,LFIRST)
                                   1
  Warning: Type mismatch in argument 'atau' at (1); passed INTEGER(4) to REAL(8)
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
 Error: Last command making (build/v14.o) returned a bad status
 Error: Make execution terminated

* Failed *
```

Does anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: Which exact errors does it give? How do the relevant parts of the code look like? How do you compile it? Show us the exact compilation command and tell us which compiler you are using. The NAMELIST is read only after the code is compiled and run. Are you running the compiled executable? How exactly? Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: @francescalus I added some detail to the original post.

Comment: @VladimirF I added some detail to the original post. Both the main code and the input file are provided in the links.

Comment: That is not enough. Really, tell us what exactly happens. Also, links are normally not acceptable for important resources. Alas, you did not even tell us if it is a runtime error or a compile-time error. What **exactly** do you run and what **exact complete** output do you get? Not *"similar errors"* give us the **exact** and **complete** output and the command which you run when the output was generated..

Comment: *"which seems to be related to the missing input file"* It does NOT seem to be related to me at all. We need the **complete output** (did I say that before?) and the relevant code to which the errors refer.

Comment: @VladimirF I cannot find the relevant part of the main code responsible for the problem. Also, the output log is so large so I just insert one error and one warning to the original post. The other ones are essentially the same but refer to different lines in the code. Regarding how I execute the code, I just open the main code with Simply Fortran and click on `build`.

Comment: How can't you able to find the relevant part of the code when the eerror message clearly says it is line 2381 in file v14.f for the first error?

Comment: this has nothing at all to do with `namelist` so i change the title. Farhad I would highly encourage you to put this away and write some simple code of your own to learn the basics (ie so you know the difference between  compile and runtime errors) before tackling what might be a significant task of modernizing a large vintage code.

Comment: Is this how _dynamic arrays_ are implemented? `DIMENSION NB(N),Y(1),YP(1),F1(1),F2(1),
     &     YN(1),YPN(1),F1N(1),F2N(1),SCR(1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take cues from the error messages, the hints are usually good. However, errors often cascade, causing other problems even in code that is fine, and that may be why you see so many messages. My advice is to fix the first error listed and try to run again.

These are the errors you've shown in your post:

1. Parity intrinsic: the problem here is the argument is not an array of logicals. Look closely - there appears to be a typo...look for a missing parenthesis. Fix it and the function should return the expected result. Try running the code. The other errors might disappear.<sup>See Note</sup>
2. Type mismatch: the message quite clearly says that an an integer (evidently single precision) was passed in but the code is expecting a real (evidently double precision). I see that implicit typing is used, so that can be the source of this particular bug. I recommend that you follow `ATAU` through the program and track what happens to it.

Also, come on NASA - Mole Scat??

---

Note: Ah, I see now: `parity` is a function defined in the MOLSCAT source code at line 11691. It is not the `parity` of the (current, 2008) Fortran standard library. It is defined with:

```
FUNCTION PARITY(I)
IMPLICIT DOUBLE PRECISION (A-H,O-Z)
PARITY=1.D0
IF((I/2)*2-I.NE.0) PARITY=-1.D0
RETURN
END
```

There is a name conflict here between the source code and the intrinsic in the F2008 standard. I'm not sure how to disable this for compatibility with F77 other than renaming the function in the source code. You may be able to place a new line in the main program: `external parity` in order to use the function as defined in MOLSCAT...There is a relevant discussion [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/535050), perhaps someone like @SteveLionel has some input.

<del>As a side note, I have no idea why this is a useful function. When would it ever return `-1.D0`?</del>

Comment: it will return `-1` if integer `i` is odd

Comment: @Matt P Thanks. I'll work on your points. Regarding the first one, the code was written in fortran 77. There are some commands in the code like `GOTO` which was deleted in the newer versions. I guess if I compile the code in f77 those kind of problems resolves.

Comment: `goto` has not been deleted.  If this is your only problem the fix is to rename `parity` to something else (you need to find it everywhere it is used of course)

Comment: `external PARITY` should be enough, or not?

Comment: @VladimirF Yes, I think so (I have already added that as an edit a few moments ago). But you would probably know better than I.

Comment: the `external parity` actually needs to go in every function/subroutine that calls `PARITY`  (It may actually be simpler to  do a global replace to change the name)

Comment: @agentp That is true. Depends on the number of call sites. Just search and replace in a good editor is faster.

Comment: I recommend renaming `PARITY` into `PARTY`. It would be fun :-)

Answer (score 3):

I'm the author of MOLSCAT so I can give some definitive answers on this one.

First, this query probably refers to MOLSCAT version 14 from 1994 or so, which was indeed written for FORTRAN 77. I can supply the current version, 2019.0 (beta), which is fully documented and will (I hope) be published in 2019. It's free.

Yes, MOLSCAT v14 has a double precision function parity which takes an integer argument and returns +1.d0 if the argument is odd and -1.d0 if it is even. FORTRAN has since introduced an intrinsic with the same name. We've renamed the function PARSGN in the current version.

MOLSCAT also uses some hokey old FORTRAN features (dating from FORTRAN IV), such as dimensioning arrays at (1) or (2) to suppress array-bound checking. It also economises on storage by passing slices of a double precision array to routines that declare them as integers. Since FORTRAN passes arrays by reference, it works, provided the compiler doesn't do over-zealous comparisons between routines. Just ignore those warnings.

There are also some other deprecated/obsolete constructs such as computed GOTO and arithmetic IF. We've mostly rewritten them in parts of the code that people actually use, but there are some little-used sections that are not worth the effort but shouldn't be deleted in case users want to reproduce old work.

Jeremy Hutson

Durham University

J.M.Hutson@durham.ac.uk

Answer (score 0):

re: the second type mismatch warning. They appear to be deliberately passing symbols to the different type:

```
 CALL CPL24(N,MXLAM,LAM,NLEV,JLEV,JLEV,J,MVALUE ....
```

note the repeated integer array `jlev` in pos 5&6, then in the sub:

```
 ENTRY CPL24(N,MXLAM,LAM,NLEV,JLEV,ATAU,J,MVAL ..
```

they have an integer and real dummy variables in those positions. Without dissecting the whole code I believe this is intentional and you should ignore the warning.

Another thing I notice, all over the place they dimension arrays `2`

```
  INTEGER J(N),L(N),LAM(2),JLEV(2)
  INTEGER PRINT
  DIMENSION ATAU(2),VL(2)
```

I'm pretty sure (having seen this before) these are actually *assumed size arrays*  ( essentially counting on the old compiler not doing bounds checking ).  That is ok but it means you will not be able to do bounds checking on this code.
Any old timers guess why they used `2` ?